# Difference between git-reset VS git-clean

Tags: git

What exactly is the difference?

My goal is to completely restore the working tree to the state when it says "no changes" - no modifications or deletions, no new untracked files, nothing.

I don't care about the .gitignore-ed files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git-reset
```

Reset current HEAD to the specified state.

for eg: `git reset --hard HEAD^` - this will remove the top commit

```
git-clean
```

Used to remove untracked files/directories from working directory

Answer (score 9):

If you want to discard all uncommitted changes:

```
git reset --hard head
```

Which will basically restore all the files that Git knows about to their last committed state.

If you want to remove all the files that Git does not know about:

```
git clean -dxf
```

This will delete everything that is ignored or not tracked.

Comment: I have a hook on my testing server that automatically pulls from repo when anyone pushes to the repo server. However, if the working tree on the testing server is not clean it aborts. So to reset the tree and return to the last good commit AND get rid of the untracked files I'd have to run 2 commands: `git reset --hard HEAD` and `git clean -f`, right?

Comment: Just `git reset --hard head` should work. Git isn't going to complain about untracked files.

Comment: unless they conflict?

Comment: If they aren't in Git what is there to conflict?

Comment: say you have an untracked file `abc.txt` hanging in working tree. A pull brings a file named exactly the same `abc.txt` *created by someone else*.

Comment: btw, **CAUTION** with the `-x` flag in `git clean`!! I just wiped out all of my untracked files (images and videos) and they DIDN'T EVEN GO TO TRASH! Does anyone know how to restore now? :-(